# I need to add day to this js?

Tags: php, javascript, time

This is my js/php displaying function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.cycle.defaults.speed   = 900;
    $.fn.cycle.defaults.timeout = 5000;

    $(function() 
    {
        $('#demos pre code').each(function() 
        {
            eval($(this).text());
        });

        $('#demos2 pre code').each(function() 
        {
            eval($(this).text());
        });
    });

    $(function($) {
      var pstOptions = {
        timeNotation: '12h',
        am_pm: true,
        utc: true,
        utc_offset: <%SETTING_TIMEOFFSET%>,
        fontFamily: 'Verdana, Times New Roman',
        fontSize: '11px',
        foreground: 'white',

        background: 'black'
      }
      $('.jclockPST').jclock(pstOptions);
    });
</script>
```

and this is my full js script:

```
/*
 * jQuery jclock - Clock plugin - v 0.2.1
 * http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jclock
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2008 Doug Sparling <http://www.dougsparling.com>
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
(function($) {

  $.fn.jclock = function(options) {
    var version = '0.2.1';

    // options
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.jclock.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $this.timerID = null;
      $this.running = false;

      $.fn.jclock.getServerOffset($this);

      var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;

      $this.timeNotation = o.timeNotation;
      $this.am_pm = o.am_pm;
      $this.utc = o.utc;
      $this.utc_offset = o.utc_offset;

      $this.css({
        fontFamily: o.fontFamily,
        fontSize: o.fontSize,
        backgroundColor: o.background,
        color: o.foreground
      });

      $.fn.jclock.startClock($this);

    });
  };

  $.fn.jclock.getServerOffset = function(el) {
    //Want to make a synchronous call to the server to get the server time.
    $.ajax({
        url: "Time.php",
        async: false,
        context: el,
        success: function(result) {
            var serverDate = new Date(+(result) * 1000); //Convert the seconds to a number, and multiple by 1000 to get milliseconds.
            var clientDate = new Date();

            $this = $(this.context[0]);

            $this.serverOffset = clientDate - serverDate; //Set the offset between server and client.
        }
    });
  };

  $.fn.jclock.startClock = function(el) {
    $.fn.jclock.stopClock(el);
    $.fn.jclock.displayTime(el);
  };

  $.fn.jclock.stopClock = function(el) {
    if(el.running) {
      clearTimeout(el.timerID);
    }
    el.running = false;
  };

  $.fn.jclock.displayTime = function(el) {
    var time = $.fn.jclock.getTime(el);
    el.html(time);
    el.timerID = setTimeout(function(){$.fn.jclock.displayTime(el)},1000);
  };

  $.fn.jclock.getTime = function(el) {  
    var now = new Date(new Date().getTime() - el.serverOffset); //Apply the server offset.
    var hours, minutes, seconds;

    if(el.utc == true) {
      if(el.utc_offset != 0) {
        now.setUTCHours(now.getUTCHours()+el.utc_offset);
      }
      hours = now.getUTCHours();
      minutes = now.getUTCMinutes();
      seconds = now.getUTCSeconds();
    } else {
      hours = now.getHours();
      minutes = now.getMinutes();
      seconds = now.getSeconds();
    }

    var am_pm_text = '';
    (hours >= 12) ? am_pm_text = " P.M." : am_pm_text = " A.M.";

    if (el.timeNotation == '12h') {
      hours = ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours);
    } else {
      hours   = ((hours <  10) ? "0" : "") + hours;
    }

    minutes = ((minutes <  10) ? "0" : "") + minutes;
    seconds = ((seconds <  10) ? "0" : "") + seconds;

    var timeNow = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if ( (el.timeNotation == '12h') && (el.am_pm == true) ) {
     timeNow += am_pm_text;
    }

    return timeNow;
  };

  // plugin defaults
  $.fn.jclock.defaults = {
    timeNotation: '24h',
    am_pm: false,
    utc: false,
    fontFamily: '',
    fontSize: '',
    foreground: '',
    background: '',
    utc_offset: 0
  };

})(jQuery);
```

How to add Date on it, so it will display Monday, Tuesday and etc ? My current time is obtained via `time.php` via

```
echo time();
```

I hope someone will be able to help me out since I dont want to break something.
It's a big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have a nice way of printing out the day name like PHP does, you have to code the names manually, starting with Sunday:

```
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var date = new Date();
console.log(days[date.getDay()]); // Wednesday
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

**EDIT:** If you want to do this all with the jclock plugin, you can use the `format` parameter to specify the output format.  The `format` symbol for the day name is `%A`.  For an example using the `format` option, see: https://github.com/dsparling/jclock/blob/master/examples/clock2.html

Comment: Your logic is correct, however you should reference to more reliable and updated documentation in your answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: I will really appreciate if its somehow possible to include it in my current code above. I really dont want to break something.

Comment: @SngeSmith: I updated my answer to cover jclock.  Without specifying exactly what you need to be outputted, I can't do the code for you.  Check out the example to see how you can specify the `format`.  Your code is also using a severely outdated version of jclock, which doesn't support day names.